# Как проверить буквы или цифры вводит пользователь в TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Есть `TextBox` в которые пользотель вводит числа или буквы. Нужно проверить и при вводе букв допустим в "год" выдать ошибку.

Comment: Привяжите ваш textbox к целочисленному свойству и переопределите `Validation.ErrorTemplate`, если надо.

Comment: А как реализовать проверку?

Comment: Проверка сама организуется :) Попробуйте! Увидите красную рамку для неправильно введённого текста.

Comment: Где это и как надо прописать?

Comment: А вы привязали textbox к целочисленному свойству? Вы вообще используете DataContext, или программируете обмен данными вручную, как на WinForms?

Comment: Нет подскажите пожалуйста как поивязать его и как использовать

Comment: Ох. То есть вы не используете `{Binding}` и даже не знаете, что это такое?

Comment: Я не смогу написать хороший пример, я с телефона. Но вам бы очень советовал почитать по Binding и MVVM.

Comment: А больше вариаетов я просто не успеваю мне скоро сдавать раблту

Comment: может это  https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.4.php

Comment: @Eikhner нет. Различайте `WPF` и `WinForms`

Comment: Ну так как можно проверить?

Comment: @KetiDzebniauri Влад вам уже все написал. Сами не попытаетесь понять?

Comment: @VladD, ваше решение тоже, с удовольствием, бы изучил. По возможности можете набросать?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, я в полностью согласен с примером AGS17. Единственно, я бы его постарался сделать покороче. `<TextBox Text="{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>` + int-свойство в VM уже достаточно для наблюдаемого эффекта, остальное служит для выдачи понятных пользователю текстовых сообщений (что не так просто!).

Answer (score 4):

Лучшее решение, я считаю, это использование прелестей `MVVM` и `Binding`. Первое, что нам следует - разделить вьюхи и логику их моделей. Второе - задать биндинг и реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` интерфейс, который нужен для оповещения вьюхи при изменении свойст на вью модели. Третье - реализовать интерфейс `IDataErrorInfo` нашей вьюмоделью.

**Итого по итогу получаем следующее:**

На вьюхе будут присутствовать элементы:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Year, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Error}" />
```

Где `UpdateSourceTrigger` служит для немедленного оповещения о изменении текста на `TextBox` элементе и `ValidatesOnDataErrors` - для включении валидации.

Сделаем два абстрактным базовых класса для упрощения:
`ViewModelBase` класс будет служить для нотификации. Он реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`интерфейс и может быть базовым классом для всех вью моделей.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T target, T source, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(target, source))
        {
            return false;
        }

        target = source;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        return true;
    }
}
```

И еще один абстрактный класс `ValidatableViewModelBase`, который наследуется от нашего `ViewModelBase` и реализует интерфейс `IDataErrorInfo`. От него будут наследоваться все вью модели, на которых необходимо что-либо валидировать:

```
public abstract class ValidatableViewModelBase : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _error;


    public string Error
    {
        get => _error;
        private set => SetProperty(ref _error, value);
    }

    public string this[string columnName] => Error = Validate(columnName);


    protected abstract string Validate(string columnName);
}
```

И в итоге вью модель целиком будет выглядеть так:
Наследуется от нашего `ValidatableViewModelBase` и в `Validate()` методе мы прописываем нашу валидацию, где `columnName` - имя нашего свойства (`Year` в нашем примере).

```
public class MainViewModel : ValidatableViewModelBase
{
    private string _year;


    public string Year
    {
        get => _year;
        set => SetProperty(ref _year, value);
    }


    protected override string Validate(string columnName)
    {
        if (columnName == nameof(Year))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Year))
            {
                return "Year field can not be empty";
            }
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Year, out var value))
            {
                return "Year field can not be converted into number";
            }
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Я предлагаю использовать для всех `TextBox`'ов биндинг на `string` свойство, потому что считаю, что парсингом и валидацией должна заниматься непостредственно вью модель, но никак не вьюха.

**Результат:**

[image: Результат]

**Почитать:**

- [`MVVM`](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/documents_WPF/level36/36_5.php)
- [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://habrahabr.ru/post/271305/)
- [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level19/19_3.php)
- [`Binding`](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php)
- [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level8/8_5.php)
- [`Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Вот что-то такое тебе нужно. Допускается ввод только 0-9 и срабатывание по нажатию Enter. Этот обработчик нужно прикрутить к `textBox` в событиях, к событию `KeyPress` в частности.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9')) return;
            if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                  //был нажат Enter
                }
                return;
            }
            else e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Решение, конечно, теоретически рабочее, но **большое фу**

Comment: Большое спасибо все сработало