# где должна производится обработка вводимых данных в паттерне MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

### задача:

есть такое окно добавления данных(фамилия и имя не должны быть пустыми, возраст - число в адекватном диапазоне, обязательно должен быть выбран пол)

[image: добавление данных]

необходимо при нажатии на **ОК** вывести информацию о всех ошибках, которые допустил пользователь.

интересует следующее (да, я знаю что 1 вопрос - 1 тема):

1. производить валидацию в модели или в представлении?
2. если в модели - то каким образом выводить информацию об ошибках?
3. можно ли в модели использовать MessageBox?
4. если в представлении - не нарушает ли это логику паттерна?
5. когда нужно использовать `IDataErrorInfo` и валидацию, а когда обойтись `get;set;`

**UPD**
проект
[ссылка на github](https://github.com/Sechik/Students)

колхоз находится в 2 файлах:

1) [тут я не придумал ничего лучше чем впихнуть проверку данных в самой модели](https://github.com/Sechik/Students/blob/master/Students/Model/Student.cs)

2) [в этом представлении у меня так же через цензуру происходит вывод сообщения об ошибке](https://github.com/Sechik/Students/blob/master/Students/StudentWindow.xaml.cs)

Как вариант исправления всего этого я вижу 1 способ: для `StudentWindow` создать отдельную модель, но чет я представить не могу что в ней писать.

Comment: Я советую [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668605/235242)

Comment: @AGS17, имеется ввиду вывод сообщения о всех ошибках после нажатия на ОК. т.е. мы ввели данные и получили все ошибки в 1 окне(ну и ждем исправления соответственно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В модели представления (она же VM). Валидация вводимых данных — типичная задача мелкой бизнес-логики.
2. Есть много способов. Лучше всего, вероятно, асинхронный интерфейс `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. (Вот ответ по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950236/276994.)
3. Строго говоря — нет. VM вообще не должна знать, выводятся ошибки в MessageBox, в строку состояния, `Popup` возле элемента с ошибкой или куда-нибудь ещё, это дело View. Правильная организация вывода ошибок — сложная тема. Умеренно простой вариант решения — [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/10105) (сервис открытия произвольных окон). Более правильное идеологически решение было бы иметь глобальный сервис отображения ошибок, для которого View предоставляет свою имплементацию.

   Это довольно сложная тема, включающая в себя в общем случае решение вопросов

   - Должны ли сообщения об ошибках автоматически исчезать через некоторое время?
   - Как юзер может убрать сообщение об ошибке?
   - Что если у нас одновременно несколько сообщений?
   - Нужны ли приоритеты по важности?
   - Что делать с повторяющимися сообщениями об ошибке (например, программа долбится в файл, защищённый от записи, и каждую секунду производит одно и то же сообщение об ошибке)

   и т. д.

   На практике, однако, (слишком) часто не заморачиваются, и пишут в VM код наподобие

   ```
   catch (Exception e) // ужасно
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error!", e.Message); // ещё ужаснее
   }
   ```

   Постарайтесь так не делать, знайте, что юзерам это не понравится.
4. Логика паттерна такова: за то, когда возникает ошибка и какова она, отвечает VM. За то, где и каким образом показывать её, отвечает View. Таким образом, логика паттерна не нарушена.
5. Это вопрос к архитектору вашего приложения, на него нету однозначного ответа. У меня в проекте, например, валидация может занимать длительное время, поэтому я не пользуюсь ни тем и ни другим, а предпочитаю третий вариант — `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. (Он позволяет асинхронную валидацию, а также кросс-валидацию: ошибка может быть не в значении *одного* свойства, а в недопустимой комбинации значений нескольких свойств!)

Comment: "не заморачиваются" чаще в WinForms, насколько я знаю там вообще нет _никаких_ способов валидации в отличие от WPF, у которого 5 (или даже больше) возможных вариантов решения данной задачи.

Comment: @Nikita: Я (слишком) часто видел такое же «решение» и в WPF, увы.

Comment: @Nikita в Winforms есть ErrorProvider (хотя его функциональность не сравнишь, конечно, с возможностями в WPF).

Comment: @VladD спасибо за ответ. можете скинуть проект, который описан в 3 пункте в ссылке?

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr: К сожалению, не могу: это коммерческий продукт, и я подписал соглашение о нераспространении.

Comment: @VladD в таком случае уточняю свой вопрос всем проектом. может вы ходябы направите на верный путь. апдейт в главном посте