# WPF&MVVM: Активация кнопки при валидных данных

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Допустим у нас есть n-ое количество `textbox` и кнопка "Добавить", которая по умолчанию неактивна и станет активной только тогда, когда все введённые данные будут валидны. Как это реализовать в MVVM?

Провека данных осуществляется при потере фокуса с поля, а следовательно до попытки преобразовать введённые данные в новый экземпляр модели (то есть до обращения к модели). `ViewModel` по концепции MVVM не имеет права ничего знать о View. Как же тогда быть? Нам нужна возможность получать состояния от всех полей, управлять этими состояниями и состоянием кнопки, а также реагировать на эти состояния сообщениями об ошибках.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы советовал абстрагировать форму ввода как отдельную вьюху (если у вас еще не так). Реализуйте интерфейс `IDataErrorInfo` вашей вьюмоделью.

Пожалуйста, [просмотрите это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668521/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-textbox/668605#668605).

Далее - сделайте простой конвертер `NonEmptyStringToBooleanConverter` и прибиндите его на `Enabled` свойство кнопки:

```
<Button Content="Submit" Enabled="{Binding Error, Converter={StaticResource NonEmptyStringToBooleanConverter}" />
```

Если не понятна идея с `NonEmptyStringToBooleanConverter`, могу объяснить подробнее.

---

Как верно заметил @Андрей, можно на кнопку повесить комманду, которая будет изменять "возможноть своего выполнения" (т.е разрешать/запрещать выполнение).

Данное решение использует классы `BindableBase` и `DelegateCommand` из библиотеки [`Prism.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/):

```
public abstract class ValidatableViewModelBase : BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand _submitCommand;
    private string _error;


    public string Error
    {
        get => _error;
        private set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _error, value))
            {
                _submitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName] => Error = Validate(columnName);


    public ICommand SubmitCommand => _submitCommand;


    protected ValidatableViewModelBase()
    {
        _submitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Submit, () => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Error));
    }


    protected abstract string Validate(string columnName);

    protected abstract void Submit();
}
```

И тогда вьюха будет выглядеть как:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Error}" />
<Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" />
```

И её вью модель:

```
public class FormViewModel : ValidatableViewModelBase
{
    private string _text;


    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => SetProperty(ref _text, value);
    }


    protected override string Validate(string columnName)
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case nameof(Text):
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
                {
                    return "Text can not be empty.";
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columnName), columnName, null);
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    protected override void Submit()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

И по итогу это будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если `Submit` необязательный, то можно сделать его виртуальным вместо абстрактного.

Comment: Хм, у нас на кнопке висит команда ведь, почему просто не воспользоваться ее `CanExecute()`? Вместо привязки к `Enabled`

Comment: @Андрей полностью с вами согласен, изначально не подумал про команду.

Answer (score 2):

В XAML разметке вашего `textbox` при привязывании используйте `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, например,

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

А в самом свойстве задайте вызов функции проверки, которая и будет принимать решение о валидности ваших данных

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, а когда функция проверки вернёт `true` или `false`, то дальше как в зависимости от этого значения показать или наоборот, не показывать сообщение об ошибке во View? Очень мало информации об `UpdateSourceTrigger`, поэтому возможно я задаю глупый вопрос по незнанию.

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучшим решением было бы не открытие доступа к кнопке по проверке валидности данных во время ввода, а проверка всех данных по нажатию кнопки, и после проверки либо принять их, либо дать сообщение пользователю с указанием его ошибок. Ну, и конечно, во втором варианте данные не принимать и оставаться на форме для корректировки введённых данных

Comment: @ Артемий Соболев: Могу привести пример, когда такой подход не очень хорош. Допустим, нужно ввести телефон (для простоты возьмём только 11-значные номера мобильных). Получается, что пока не будет введена одиннадцатая цифра, при вводе каждого символа будет сообщение о неверно введённых данных. Наверное, в этом случае нужно будет при вводе каждого символа лишь проверять, является ли он цифрой, а итоговую проверку запускать только когда будет введена одиннадцатая цифра...

Comment: Никто не мешает объединить оба метода проверки

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей в рамках MVVM используется `RelayCommand`. Предлагаю, если Вы работаете с MVVM, написать свою маленькую dll где будут хелперы, вроде этой `RelayCommand` и прочих интересных вещей, например `IObservableProperty`. У меня у самого есть своя dll где есть набор стилей, хелперов, кастомных контролов и прочих вещей которые помогают при разработке.

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> m_command;
        private readonly Func<bool> m_canExecute;  

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> _command,Func<bool> _canExecute)
        {
            m_command = _command;
            m_canExecute = _canExecute;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
            if(handler == null)
                return;

            handler.Invoke(this,new EventArgs());
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object _entity)
        {
            return m_canExecute == null || m_canExecute(_entity);
        }

        public void Execute(object _entity)
        {
            m_command(_entity);
        }

    }
```

Comment: А можно использовать [Prism](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/), который в себе уже содержит best practices для работы с WPF от Microsoft ([документашка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)) :)